# Set all the properties that are null to empty in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, null

I have an object with 10 properties some of which are null. i need them to be empty strings instead.

Here is the code, but the properties are not being set to empty strings

```
$.each(elt, function (key, value) {
  if (value === null) {
    value = "";
  }
});
```

elt is an object.

Comment: `value` is just a value, it is not a reference to the object property. `value = "";` doesn't change the value that is stored on the object property, it simply replaces the value stored in the `value` variable with a new value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the key, since the value is just a copy of the property value:

```
$.each(elt, function (key, value) {
  if (value === null) {
    elt[key] = "";
  }
});
```

Comment: You're welcome :) If my answer helped you, fell free to upvote and/or accept it!

Comment: I had to wait to accept:) Don't mind the downvoters - there are a lot of people with too much free time on their hands.